# jasmine spy not called

Tags: javascript, jasmine, spy

I'm new to jasmine spies.

Here is my test:

```
spyOn(gapi, 'ready').andCallThrough();
inject(function(_endpointService_) {
  endpointService = _endpointService_;
});        
var _doSteps = gapi.ready.mostRecentCall.args[0];
var wrapper = {_doSteps: _doSteps};
spyOn(wrapper, '_doSteps');
gapi.ready(); //calls _doSteps through promise in service.
//_doSteps();
expect(wrapper._doSteps).wasCalled(); //gives error - not called.
```

as in my endpointService I have:

```
gapi.ready($endpointService._doSteps);
return $endpointService;
```

and my _doSteps method:

```
_doSteps: function(){
   console.log('in dosteps!');
 },
```

it logs 'in dosteps!' before the spy complains that _doSteps wasn't called. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your spyOn() function returns a spy object - so I'me not sure why you are using mostRecentCall and the wrapper ?

```
var gapi = new Gapi(); // must create a variable to spy on.
var readySpy = spyOn(gapi, 'ready').andCallThrough();
// .. something that calls gapi.ready here
expect(readySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```